# Maintaining a map that contains a map

Tags: java

I have a map as shown below in which there is a key and values is of type `List`:

```
Map<String, List<String> newdatamap = new HashMap<>();
map.put ("payerName", Arrays.asList("wpn", "wpfnb", "dgeft", "xbthy"));
map.put ("fixedRate", Arrays.asList("dd", "ww", "trrty", "httyure"))
```

I'd like to add another map over the previous map, such that there is a key and its value will be the above map. Is this the correct data structure, and how do we implement it?

I want something like this shown below

```
Key         Value

B1          payerName  ----> "wpn", "wpfnb", "dgeft", "xbthy"
            fixedRate ----->"dd", "ww", "trrty", "httyure"



B2          payerName  ----> "SSSwpn", "wpfSSSnb", "GGGdgeft", "xbtYYYYhy"
            fixedRate ----->"WWdd", "wTTYw", "YYYYtrrty", "IIIhttyure"
```

As shown above, only a new key is been introduced to the map, and its value is the previous map. Is a `Map` data structure the correct way to go about this, or do any other data structures work better?

Folks please advise as suggested in answers also will guava library will support JDK 1.5 also

Comment: `Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>`?

Comment: So, you want a `Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>`? What's your question exactly? What's the problem? My advice is that with such a complex data structure, you'll quickly lose yourself, and it's almost certainly a sign of a lack of design and encapsulation. You should probaly define classes, that would have names. You can see a country, containing cities containing streets as a Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>, but it's more readable to see it as a Country, containing a Map<String, City>, where City contains a List<Street>.

Answer (score 1):

From what it *reads* like...you want a `Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>>`.

It's easy enough to declare...

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> values = new HashMap<>();
```

...but not enjoyable to index into:

```
// get B2's fixed rates
values.get("B2").get("fixedRate");
```

Perhaps instead you should consider [Guava's `Table`](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Table) class instead.  It will give you clear coordinates to what object you want to get, as well as preserve the overall structure you have.

```
final Table<String, String, List<String>> values = HashBasedTable.create();
values.put("B1", "payerName", Lists.newArrayList("wpn", "wpfnb", "dgeft", "xbthy"));
System.out.println(values.get("B1", "payerName")); // prints the list
```

Comment: This misses the fact that he's trying to use multiple map levels to construct parallel arrays instead of using classes to group related values.

Comment: There's definitely value in encapsulating their desired functionality, but I'm not opposed to using a `Table` structure.  If you wanted to provide a solution in which the values were encapsulated, I'd both encourage and upvote it.

Comment: @Makoto's I am using JDK 1.5 so please advise will guava library for Table support JDK 1.5